# Error in passing the address of a pointer holding array elements to a function in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I created an array of characters and then assigned them to a pointer. Then I passed that pointer address to a function which would reverse the array character by character and print them out. I can not understand the error in my code.

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. 
// Program execution begins and ends there.

#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void reverses(char* p) {
    int count = 17;
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {

        cout << *(p + i);
        char temp = *(p + i);
        *(p + i) = *(p + count);
        *(p + count) = temp;
        count--;
        cout << *(p + i);           
    }
}
int main() {
    char names[18] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 
                       'j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r' };
    char* ptr = &names[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        reverses(ptr + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what error. Note that the very first text appears to be a comment found in a lot of "try to solve this" problem sites. If that text appears in your code, remove it. But what is your error?

Comment: Joseph he is getting garbage due to going out of bound of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the reverse function 18 times in a loop, and each time you pass a pointer to the next character of the char array, so after the second loop you are already accessing elements out of the bounds of the array.

Call `reverses` only once, and print the characters after the reversion is complete.

```
void reverses(char* p) {
    int count = 17;
    for (int i = 0; i < 18 / 2; i++) {
        char temp = *(p + i);
        *(p + i) = *(p + count);
        *(p + count) = temp;
        count--;  
    }
}

int main()
{
    char names[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                      'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'};
    char *ptr = &names[0];
    reverses(ptr);

    for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
        std::cout << ptr[i];
    }  
}
```

Note that for a trivial reverse routine, only half of the cycles are needed otherwise you are returning the array to it's original form.

---

Here is a simplified, and thus more readable version where you pass the size of the array as an argument:

```
void reverses(char *p, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++, size--) // size would be 18
    {
        char temp = p[i]; // swap routine
        p[i] = p[size - 1];
        p[size - 1] = temp;      
    }
}
```

Using `[]` array notation is simpler and more readable, but if you prefer you can use the pointer notation:

```
void reverses(char *p, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++, size--)
    {
        char temp = *(p + i);
        *(p + i) = *(p + size - 1);
        *(p + size - 1) = temp;      
    }
}
```

The same end result, but less readable code.

---

I would use algorithm library `std::reverse`:

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::reverse(ptr, ptr + 17);

for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
    std::cout << ptr[i];
}
```